# How to clear the div(contenteditable) area with js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I send some data and I wanna clear the content-editable div area.

The vaule of the div is empty but in the screen there is a text left.

It is a SPA Vue.js project.

```html
<div id="chattingContents" class="chattingContents" contenteditable="true" :style="flexablePadding" @input="sync" v-html="innerContent"></div>
<input type="text" v-model="contents" style="display: none;">
```

```
export default {
  data: function(){
        return {
          (...)
          formShow: false,
          contents: '',
          innerContent:'',
          (...)
        }
      },
  methods: {
    (...)
    formToggle(){
        this.stampShow= false
        this.stampAreaShow= false
        this.contents = ''
        this.innerContent = this.contents
        this.formShow = !this.formShow
      },
    createNotify(){
      (...)
      else if(!this.stampAreaShow&&this.contents&&!this.uploadedImage) {//text only
          axios.post('/create_notify', {notify_type: 'text',contents: this.contents}).then((res)=>{
            if (res.data != null){
              alert("メッセージ送信完了！")
              this.formToggle();
              this.fetchNotifies();
            }
          }, (error) =>{
            console.log(error)
          })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you ever tried remove element using this.$el?

Answer (score 0):

okay, it was about ''. 
If I change (this.contents = '') into (this.contents = ""), it works.
But I don't know why...
What's the difference between single quotation and double quotation?